# Why is the is_integer() method not working?

Tags: python, python-2.7, floating-point

I wrote this code in Python:

```
x=345**3
z=float(x)**(1.0/3.0)
print z
print z.is_integer()
```

The output is:

```
345.0
False
```

Why is that? I expected the output to be `True`.

Comment: @ThiefMaster that's not what's going on here. `int(z).is_integer()` gives an `AttributeError`, because [`is_integer` is a float instance method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#float.is_integer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `z` isn't exactly `345.0`:

```
>>> x = 345 ** 3
>>> z = float(x) ** (1.0 / 3.0)
>>> print z
345.0
>>> (345.0).is_integer()
True
```

All good so far, however:

```
>>> z.is_integer()
False
>>> z == 345.0
False
>>> z
344.9999999999999
```

This is just a display issue, due to the difference in `str` and `repr` forms of `float`:

```
>>> z.__repr__()
'344.9999999999999'
>>> z.__str__()
'345.0'
```

Comment: is he looking if z is an integer or if it is finite with an integer value ?

Comment: @Begueradj given that the OP is calling `z.is_integer()`, an instance method that only `float` objects have, rather than `isinstance(z, int)`, it seems sensible to assume the latter.

Answer (score 0):

You are raising a non-integer to the power of a non-integer, so the result is a non-integer

Comment: But `(x ** y) ** (1.0 / y) == x`, so the OP is (reasonably) expecting that the result, although a `float` object, would have an integer value

Comment: On top of which, the suggested implication is false: there are plenty of examples (both mathematically and with floating-point) where raising an non-integer to a non-integer gives an integer.

Comment: Indeed, but python recognizes float(int) as a float, even though it can be in fact an int

Comment: @CIsForCoocckies yes, and Python `float` objects have a special method, `is_integer`, to test whether `int(f) == f`. The OP *knows* `z` is a `float`, otherwise they'd get an `AttributeError`. This is **not** the same as `isinstance(z, int)`.